# Only small part of one function is working

Tags: python, function

I wrote 2 functions and I executed them nested. But one of my functions is not working properly. It's first line is working fine but other lines are not working. Output does not show anything.
The main idea of my code is price / quality comparison. So i created 2 list and put the qualities and prices. Note: GreenGroce, Bakery etc. are the list of the prices.

```
def comparing(qualities, aisle):
  empty_dict =  {}
  for i in range(0, 4, 1):
    for x in markets:
      comparing_score = aisle[i] / qualities[i]
      empty_dict.update({x : comparing_score})
    if i == 4:
      print(empty_dict)
#There is a function which compares the input arguments.

def shopping():
  compare_selection = int(input('Lütfen hangi ürünü kıyaslamak istediğinizi giriniz: ''\nManav Reyonu(1), Unlu Mamüller(2), Meşrubatlar(3), Baharat Çeşitleri(4), Baklagiller(5) '))
  if compare_selection == 1:
      comparing(qualities, GreenGroce)
  elif compare_selection == 2:
      comparing(qualities, Bakeries)
  elif compare_selection == 3:
       comparing(qualities, Drinks)
  elif compare_selection == 4:
      comparing(qualities, Spices)
  elif compare_selection == 5:
      comparing(qualities, legumes)
```

And then i called them in somewhere but except for the first line of my code, none of the lines worked.

Comment: "But one of my functions is not working properly" — _which_ one?

Comment: only shopping's first line is working. others are not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `comparing()` function only prints something `if i == 4:`, but it never is. Inside the `for i in range(0, 4, 1):` loop the values of `i` are `0` → `3`.

So I believe you are mistakenly thinking the `shopping()` function not working.

Comment: @Berkay: You're welcome. Note that  `range(0, 4, 1)` is equivalent to `range(4)`. (See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).)